# Commands to search by project homepage tag

Tags: search, aptitude, apt-cache

Some packages list a homepage, such as the one for Texmaker.

```
$ apt-cache show texmaker | grep http
Homepage: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/
```

However, I can't find a way to search for the URL of a homepage.

```
$ apt-cache search xm1math.net
$ aptitude search xm1math.net
$ axi-cache search xm1math.net
0 results found.
Did you mean: mpmath.net ?
More terms: 
More tags:
```

The man pages are not especially helpful.

Edit: this has been a feature request for `apt-cache` since 2008.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=484485